# Count appearances on string and output a list with character - appearances

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am making a codewars kata on Scala. I am still a starter on that language and I am trying to do things in a functional programming way, which is also a mistery for me.

The idea of the task is simple, they provide you a string and you need to output a List with the characters and the number of times that it is on the list. It should be easy:

Kata.orderedCount("abracadabra") == List(('a', 5), ('b', 2), ('r', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)

And this is the code I am writting. I also do not understand why I am can not print out of the loop list_final, even though I put it as a return (explanation here could be nice too). It should be just to find a way to append the new list to an existing one but lists in scala are inmmutable :(. Thanks in advance

```
var cuerda = "abracadabra" 
var cuerda2 = cuerda.groupBy(word => word)
var cont:Int = 0
var list288 = List[Any]()
var vector = new Array[Any](cuerda.distinct.size)
cuerda.map(cuerda2).distinct.foreach(e=> {
  println(List(e(0).toString, e.size))
  var list_final = list288 ::: List(e(0).toString, e.size)
  cont+=1
  vector = vector +: Array(e(0), e.size)
  println(list_final)

})
println(list288)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit easier in Scala:

```
val cuerda = "abracadabra"
cuerda.groupBy(identity).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.length }.toList
```

There may be an even easier way.

**Edit:**
And there is, thanks Tim:

```
cuerda.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).toList
```

**Update:**
Since you want to maintain order, you can do something like this:

```
val counts = cuerda.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
cuerda.distinct.map(c => c -> counts(c)).toList
```

Again, there may be a better way.

Comment: `.mapValues(_.length)`

Comment: Do you know why can not I print the list out of the loop?

Comment: Actually, it does not work. Because it outputs it in the different order that the test case.

Comment: @Borja_042 I edited my question so you can maintain order. I don't know about your println question, sorry.

Comment: `cuerda.distinct.map(c => c -> cuerda.count(_ == c)).toList` (assuming that `distinct` maintains order, which is not clear from the documentation but works in practice)